# How to require some properties but allow more?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a function which takes in an argument which needs at least one property on it, but could have more.  Something like this:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

function someFunc(obj) {
    // do something
}

someFunc({bar: 'test', biff: 'test2'})
```

Where the `obj` being passed in to `someFunc` could have any props on it, but must have `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this will already work like that if your argument is not an object literal.

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

function someFunc(obj: Foo) {
    // do something
}

const foo = {
  bar: 'test',
  biff: 'test2'
}

someFunc(foo)
```

If you want to be explicit about it, and allow object literals to contain excess properties as well, you can add what's called an *index signature*.

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  [index: string]: unknown;
}

function someFunc(obj: Foo) {
    // do something
}

someFunc({
  bar: 'test',
  biff: 'test2'
})
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to make your `obj` parameter typed you can use `{[key: string]: any}`

This means the input is an object which has one or many properties and type of each property could be `any`

```
function someFunc(obj: {[key: string]: any}) {
    // do something
}
```